# OS X Mountain Lion has multiple Finder windows open

Tags: macos, osx-mountain-lion, finder

My wife's computer has had a lot of Finder windows all opening at the same time, and it bogs the computer down. When we restart it it relaunches again with hundreds of Finder windows.

Comment: We'd need a lot more details to know what is going on. What machine, which operating system? Any special configuration?

Comment: @vonbrand The operating system is OS X Mountain Lion, as the OP indicated in the tags. The machine is mostly irrelevant with OS X.

Answer (score 1):

I think your version of OSX will automatically re-open any open Finder windows that were open before shutting down.

Possible solutions:

1. Use the keyboard shortcut Command-Option-W to close all windows.
2. or use the Terminal application to shutdown and restart the Finder application:

   - open Terminal
   - type 'killall Finder' and hit return.